# Swift Alamofire Mapper

Tags: ios, swift

Swift Alamofire Mapper doesn't map array of String with null.

For example, we have:

```
["first_item", "second_item", null]
```

When I use Alamofire Mapper it returns empty array like -> [], 
how can I handle null value in array when our service response like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your code of doing this mapping so that we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

finally i found how to figure this :) my model was like bellow:

```
    import ObjectMapper
    struct DataItems: Mappable {

    var rulesUrl: String? 
    var isAvailable: Bool? 
    var companyName: String? 
    var offers: [String]? 

    required init?(map: Map){}

    func mapping(){
    ..... mapping
    }
}
```

in this model when i wanted to map my responseString to this model, if in offers we have something like ["offer_1","offer_2",null] from server, alamofire return nil for offers. but after than i change offers: [String]? to offers[String?]? and then it works as good as i want :) and now it like bellow :

```
import ObjectMapper
struct DataItems: Mappable {

  var rulesUrl: String? 
  var isAvailable: Bool? 
  var companyName: String? 
  var offers: [String?]? 

  required init?(map: Map){}

  func mapping(){
..... mapping
   }

}
```

i hope it can help other people.